# Bailey's curdled in coffee?

Tags: food-safety, coffee, cream, alcohol, liqueur

I put an irish bar's baileys into my morning's black coffee I kept warm in a Stanley thermos. But after an indeterminate amount of time (between 10 mins to an hour), some of the milk curdled.

Is that normal? Should I have been concerned? Is it because my coffee turned out that acidic?? We use a french press and preground beans. I haven't taken a look at where he buys his bean grounds, but offhand it tastes like a medium roast.

Comment: When you say "an irish bar's baileys" do you mean it's a house-made irish cream liqueur and not the name-brand Baileys Irish Cream produced by Diageo?

Comment: Most likely it's brand name; I haven't peered at their liquor rack from the right angle. I'm new to bars and pubs so I'm unsure what information is relevant

Comment: Is it the kind of bar that sells a lot of Baileys? (Meaning, do you think it's been on the shelf less than a week, or it could have been there for a couple of years)

Comment: I think milk can curdle when something acidic is introduced. Coffee is acidic

Comment: Well also alcohol can curdle milk

Comment: Hi, acid and high temperature can curdle milk. In case of coffee I would suggest that heat is the main factor.